# How can I make these components navigate to another screen in react?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on a react project that has a navigation page with widgets that navigate to various parts of the app. However, I'm not sure how to make them navigate to their appropriate screens.

Edit:

I have added more of the code in order to better illustrate what I am trying to do. [image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import LinearGradientScreen from './linearGradientScreen';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
const CellComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('tabNavigator')}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: props.item.color,
        height: (13 * Dimensions.get('window').height) / 100,
        width: 132,
        borderRadius: 5,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(52,2,2,1)',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 3,
          height: 3,
        },
        elevation: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        margin: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      {props.item.family === 'Feather' ? (
        <Feather
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons1' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'Entypo' ? (
        <Entypo
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons2' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'FontAwesome' ? (
        <FontAwesome
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      <Text
        style={{
          color: 'white',
          fontSize: 18 * Dimensions.get('window').fontScale,
        }}>
        {props.item.name}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <LinearGradientScreen>
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text
          style={{
            marginTop: '20%',
            fontSize: 50 * Dimensions.get('window').fontScale,
            color: 'white',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}>
          Home
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 25 * Dimensions.get('window').fontScale,
            color: 'white',
            fontWeight: '400',
            marginBottom: '10%',
          }}>
          Select a service
        </Text>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={2}
          data={HomeScreenData}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <CellComponent {...props} item={item} />;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </LinearGradientScreen>
  );
};
const HomeScreenData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'AI Chat',
    icon: 'cpu',
    family: 'Feather',
    color: 'rgba(247,52,122,1)',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Live Chat',
    icon: 'wechat',
    family: 'FontAwesome',
    color: 'rgba(16,165,245,1)',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Resources',
    icon: 'file-document-outline',
    family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons',
    color: 'rgba(74,74,74,1)',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Client Connect',
    icon: 'gesture-swipe-horizontal',
    family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons1',
    color: 'rgba(237,41,57,1)',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'DM',
    icon: 'message',
    family: 'Entypo',
    color: 'rgba(74,144,226,1)',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Profile',
    icon: 'tooltip-account',
    family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons2',
    color: 'rgba(144,19,254,1)',
  },
];
export default HomeScreen;
```

Is there something like  navigate: `'AiScreen.js',` that I can use to make it navigate to the correct place?

Comment: Your question is kind not very clear, state how many screens are there and how you want the navigation flow to go. Also show the code that you have tried up until now

Comment: sorry for the confusion. There are 6 screens and I want each widget to navigate to its appropriate screen when pressed. ai chat would navigate to ai screen for example

Comment: I've added the whole thing to question. Hope this makes things more clear

Comment: no evidence of a router - You'll need to implement a router to accomplish your goal. There are several. If you want a turnkey solution investigate nextjs - otherwise perhaps react-router would work for you.

Comment: It's fairly easy, you can use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating

Comment: So would I just put onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')} under each of the constants? is that what u mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output:

[image]

Here is an example, here I have Implemented How you can navigate to the Ai Chat Screen, Just like that you can create other screens, define them in Stack Navigator and navigate within them.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

function AiChatScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Ai AiChatScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AI Chat" component={AiChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Resources" component={ResourcesScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DM" component={DmScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Live Chat" component={LiveChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Client Connect" component={ClientConnectScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function LiveChatScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Live Chat Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ResourcesScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Resources Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ClientConnectScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Client Connect Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function DmScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>DM Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modified CellComponent, it takes `props.item.name` for routing.

So, you don't have to worry about typing the route name for each screen.

```js
const CellComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(props.item.name)}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: props.item.color,
        height: (13 * Dimensions.get('window').height) / 100,
        width: 132,
        borderRadius: 5,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(52,2,2,1)',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 3,
          height: 3,
        },
        elevation: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        margin: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      {props.item.family === 'Feather' ? (
        <Feather
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons1' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'Entypo' ? (
        <Entypo
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons2' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'MaterialCommunityIcons' ? (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      {props.item.family === 'FontAwesome' ? (
        <FontAwesome
          type={props.item.type}
          color={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
          name={props.item.icon}
          size={30}
        />
      ) : null}
      <Text
        style={{
          color: 'white',
          fontSize: 18 * Dimensions.get('window').fontScale,
        }}>
        {props.item.name}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation?platform=android&name=Getting%20started%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnew-screen.js)

Comment: Does the initial route name have to be the very first screen the user encounters? Because I have a login screen that precedes the home screen and It starred having issues now

Comment: I have updated the whole codebase, please go to the Expo Snack link given below for detailed implementation. You can see the app behavior in the uploaded screengrab

Comment: Oh okay gotcha. It's saying that the action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "AI Chat"} was not handled by any navigator. I replaced all of the instances if ai chat with the actual screen name which is AiScreen. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: About the query in the comment, I might have to take look at the code before making any suggestions.

Comment: haha of course. you were extremely helpful. Thank you sm.

Comment: and I upvoted but my reputation is low so it isn't showing up :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225299/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-john-green).

Answer (score 2):

Every Stack.Screen should receive the prop "name" to make it available on "navigation.navigate("RouteName")".

from the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
    
    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Details"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
export default HomeScreen;
```

If you named your routes like in the docs

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import DetailsScreen from "~/pages/Detail";
import HomeScreen from "~/pages/Home";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator "initialRouteName="Home"  >
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Same way you have "initialRouteName="Home" on <Stack.Navigator/> component that matches with the name you passed to <Stack.Screen/> "name" props

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but what do youm nea by "the name you gave to <Stack.Screen/> component."?

Comment: Is about the prop "name" that every Stack.Screen should receive to make it available on "navigation.navigate("RouteName")".
The same way you have "initialRouteName="Home" on <Stack.Navigator/> component that matches with the name you passed to <Stack.Screen/>